# in css - how to draw squares only on top row, bottom row and most right column of screen

Tags: css

I want to draw divs (50 little squares) on 3 lines: 20 on top most row of container,20 bottom row of container and 10 most right column of container.
something like that:

```
*******
      *
      *
*******
```

I tried with flexbox and failed. then I tried something like that and failed:

```
.board{
  position: relative;
  height: 445px;
  width: 840px;
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid rgb(8, 8, 8);
  display: block;
  background-color: grey; 
}


.top-row{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.bottom-row{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.right-column{
  top: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
}
```

the actual is not good. also not responsive as I wish

Comment: I forgot the box item itself (the square style):   .box {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    background-color: blue;
}

Comment: What you mean a behavior of "responsive"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another flex example: I made your blue box larger to indicate numbering.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  background-color: blue;
}

.row-ends {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.row-mid {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  display: inline;
  width: 20px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  font-size: 9px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row-ends">
    <div class="item top">1</div>
    <div class="item top">2</div>
    <div class="item top">3</div>
    <div class="item top">4</div>
    <div class="item top">5</div>
    <div class="item top">6</div>
    <div class="item top">7</div>
    <div class="item top">8</div>
    <div class="item top">9</div>
    <div class="item top">10</div>
    <div class="item top">11</div>
    <div class="item top">11</div>
    <div class="item top">13</div>
    <div class="item top">14</div>
    <div class="item top">15</div>
    <div class="item top">16</div>
    <div class="item top">17</div>
    <div class="item top">18</div>
    <div class="item top">19</div>
    <div class="item top">20</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-mid">
    <div class="item top">1</div>
    <div class="item top">2</div>
    <div class="item top">3</div>
    <div class="item top">4</div>
    <div class="item top">5</div>
    <div class="item top">6</div>
    <div class="item top">7</div>
    <div class="item top">8</div>
    <div class="item top">9</div>
    <div class="item top">10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-ends">
    <div class="item top">1</div>
    <div class="item top">2</div>
    <div class="item top">3</div>
    <div class="item top">4</div>
    <div class="item top">5</div>
    <div class="item top">6</div>
    <div class="item top">7</div>
    <div class="item top">8</div>
    <div class="item top">9</div>
    <div class="item top">10</div>
    <div class="item top">11</div>
    <div class="item top">11</div>
    <div class="item top">13</div>
    <div class="item top">14</div>
    <div class="item top">15</div>
    <div class="item top">16</div>
    <div class="item top">17</div>
    <div class="item top">18</div>
    <div class="item top">19</div>
    <div class="item top">20</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

With flexbox you can try this:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.container > div {
  width:calc(100% / 20); /*20 div per row*/
  background:red;
  border:1px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
/*keep the square ratio*/
.container > div:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
/**/
/*use a big margin to push to the right from the 21th element*/
.container > div:nth-child(n + 21) {
  background:green;
  margin-left:calc(100% - 100% / 20);
}
/*reset the margin after the 31th element */
.container > div:nth-child(n + 31) {
  background:blue;
  margin-left:0;
}


/* Irrelevant styles */
.container {
  counter-reset: section;
}
.container > div {
 position:relative;
}
.container > div::after {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @EvaCohen don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your issue ;)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @EvaCohen there is a tick icon under the upvote/downvote of the answer, simply click on it

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try CSS grid.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);
 height: 100vh;
}


.top {
  background: lightblue;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.right {
  background: red;
  grid-column-start: 20;
}

.bottom {
  background: green;
    grid-row-start: 12;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>


    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>


    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```